# How to copy particular lines below particular text?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, terminal, sh

Suppose I have long text files `output1`, `output2`, and `output3`. In all output files, somewhere is "My Name is Rock (static)"
and below that text some values like

```
"My Name is Rock (static)"
10 20 30
-10 0.5 00
3.0 0.0 0.0 (different for all output file)
```

How can I copy the second column of the third line below the line ("My Name is Rock (static)") to a new file?

Remember line numbers are different for all output file.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'c{c--;if(!c) print $2}/My Name is Rock \(static\)/{c=3}' ./output1 ./output2 ./output3
```

#### Explanation

- `/My Name is Rock \(static\)/{c=3}`: When "My Name is Rock (static)" is seen, set `c` to 3
- `c{...}`: If the counter `c` is non-zero, do `...` (note, `c` starts off at 0)
- `c--;if(!c) print $2`: Decrement counter, if counter is now zero, print 2nd field of current line